# Laser scan matcher with few scan points

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS-Community

I have a question regarding localization with a laser scanner.
I am planing to use a Hokuyo Laser Scanner to localize my robot. I tried the laser scan matcher package in a small room and it worked perfectly. The robot is meant to operate on a table 2x3 meters in size. On each corner there are 8x8x8 cm beacons and a large semicircle on the side which must be used for localization.
The sensor will see something like the figure below.

```
   _                       ___________                          _
  |_|                     |           |                        |_|
                           \_________/  
  






   _                                                            _
  |_|                                                          |_|
```

Is it possible to use the laser scan matcher package on an environment with few objects to match such as the beacons above? Odometry information will be available. At the moment, the laser is not available, so I can't test it. My guess is, that the laser scan matcher package works mainly with straight lines.

Thank you in advance for your answers

Steve

---

Appended

---

Ok, thank you. I will try to limit the FOV of the laser. I thought of tracking the beacons. Since I know their initial position and the laser operates with 10 Hz I can create for each beacon a ROI and ignore the remainig scans. Then it shouldn't (theoretically) matter if there are moving objects around the table. As soon as the laser is available, I will try this. Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55204/laser-scan-matcher-with-few-scan-points/) by [funas1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4204/funas1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It should work in principle. Is there nothing around it? In a normal rooms you'd usually find "stuff" within 5.6m, so the scan matcher should have more to align on.

Regarding stability: What is your desired application? Because the laser_scan_matcher package does not provide localization, just incrementally matched lasers, i.e. it will drift.

People moving around the table could be really bad as the scanmatcher can't know what to consider and what not. So it will come up with the best match, that might focus on something else than the small table legs. You might need to do something more advanced like actual localization or specific to the task. Maybe you could get away with limiting the FOV of the laser, but you'll definitely have to test that scenario.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0